# How to write value in 1 column when value in other column changes?

Tags: excel, vba

**EDIT**:

So I'm trying to see if the first 4 characters after the `-` are the same or different. If the characters are the same, e.g. **ALEGRALL-1BLU4060 & ALEGRALL-1BLU5080** we would write `1` to only the first match, and skip any of those that match. But when we come across values like **ACADIACA-1BLK537A & ACADIACA-1GRY537A** we would write `1` to both, because they have unique 4 letter strings (1BLK & 1GRY).

[image]

So ideally my output would look like this. So we are basically checking if the previous cell has different value to the next cell, the criteria being the first 4 characters after the **-**

[image]

I tried this simple formula, but its writing to every cell.

```
=IF(O2<>O3,1,"")
```

I also tried (but this writes 1 to the last match in a set of matching strings, my desired output would be writing 1 to the FIRST mastch). This is close:

```
=IF(LEFT(A3,4) = LEFT(A4,4),"",1)
```

Comment: Are you interested if everything preceding the "-" is changing? There are no identical values in the screenshot you shared.

Answer (score 0):

So test the second against the first and if the same leave blank but if different put a 1.

[image]

I used left() with 4 characters but you could do 6 or 8 as needed.

This will put a 1 as soon as the tested list changes - unlike your example which puts a 1 until it sees a change, which is not what you described.

Comment: This is very close, but only thing it doesn't do is write `1` to the FIRST unique value. It seems to write it to the last unique value on a set of matches, e.g. **1BLU4060 & 1BLU50801 & BLU80A0** it writes `1` to the last one, **BLU80A0**

Comment: @Tony writes 1 to the first in my example... ALE2 ASH3 etc...